# What does the user "nobody" represent in server process logs

Tags: linux, vps

I am new to vps hosting. I checked daily process logs on my server and found a user with name nobody consuming more memory than others.

So what is the user nobody related to and why is it consuming more memory?

This is the log info I found:

```
user / cpu / mem / mysql  
nobody / 0.00 / 27.31 / 0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Apache, MySQL, and other common servers and background tasks (daemons) run under the 'nobody' user. From the Wikipedia entry for [nobody](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobody_%28username%29):

> "In many Unix variants, "nobody" is the
>   conventional name of a user account
>   which owns no files, is in no
>   privileged groups, and has no
>   abilities except those which every
>   other user has.
>
> It is common to run daemons as nobody,
>   especially servers, in order to limit
>   the damage that could be done by a
>   malicious user who gained control of
>   them."

You're seeing the 'nobody' user because you're probably running a server or background process on the box. It's nothing to worry about.